# Problem with implementing RainbowKit for wallets

Tags: wallets, react, rainbowkit

I am integrating **RainbowKit** into my dapp to make connecting and disconnecting wallets easier. I am using **Nextjs** to develop a NFT marketplace.

I am given this strange error while running the project on my local server. The error belongs to the **RainbowKit** package. I have tried deleting my **node_modules** and running `npm install`, but it does not help.

Despite what the error says, I have not used `.map()` function anywhere in my script.

Do you happen to know how I can overcome this issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oooops! There was a missing `chains={chains`} code in my _app.js file where you need to wrap up the entire project by **WagmiConfig** and
**RanibowKitProvider**

```
return (
    <WagmiConfig client={wagmiClient}>

       // My problem used to belong here ...
      <RainbowKitProvider chains={chains}>

        <YourApp />

      </RainbowKitProvider>

    </WagmiConfig>
  );
```